# PHP POST Rest Service, save image sent via $_FILES

Tags: php, rest, file-upload, curl

I made a REST Service which is heavily based on [this tutorial](http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/). I also made a REST Request library which is heavily based on [this tutorial](http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/making-restful-requests-in-php/). (Basically, a bunch of `switch` on `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`). the api also make requests with cURL.

```
protected function executePost ($ch)
{
    if (!is_string($this->requestBody))  
    {  
        $this->buildPostBody();  
    }  

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->requestBody);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  

    $this->doExecute($ch); 
}

protected function doExecute (&$curlHandle)
{
    $this->setCurlOpts($curlHandle);  
    $this->responseBody = curl_exec($curlHandle);  
    $this->responseInfo = curl_getinfo($curlHandle);  

    curl_close($curlHandle);  
}
```

I have 2 simple HTML forms, one with a get method and one for the post method. When i use one of them with simple input text, works fine. I get/return the values in the service with no problem.

But I need to send an image from a HTML form, receive it in my service and then save it on the server.

Here is the part where I lunch make the query to the service.

```
print_r($_FILES);
//move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["image1"]["tmp_name"], "Images/" . $_FILES["image1"]["name"] ); when uncommented, This line actually works and save the image in my folder.

include("RestUtils.php");

$request = new RestRequestOperator('http://localhost:8080/REST/RestControler.php/user/1', 'POST', $_FILES);  
$request->execute();
```

In my service, I receive the image infos , which are the tmp_name and the name. When I try to save the image with move_uploaded_file(  and the right parameters , it doesn't work.

I realise there is some sort of magic going there with the image file saved for a 'short laps of time' in the tmp folder. when i call my service, the image is already removed ?

Wrap up : I wonder if it is possible to send an image to a PHP REST API and they save it on their server.

EDIT : I added in the service.

```
if(file_exists($_POST["image1"]["tmp_name"] )){
     echo "file EXISTS<br>";
}else echo "NOPE.<br>";

if(is_uploaded_file($_POST["image1"]["tmp_name"] )){
     echo "is_uploaded_file TRUE<br>";
}else echo "is_uploaded_file FALSE<br> .";

if(move_uploaded_file( $_POST["image1"]["tmp_name"], "Images/" .$_POST["image1"]["name"] )){
     echo "move_uploaded_file SUCCESS ";
}else echo "NOT move_uploaded_file";
```

outputs : file EXISTS , is_uploaded_file FALSE, NOT move_uploaded_file
which means the file actually still exist in the service but is uploaded file returns falses, probably beacause I use the POST array in the service instead of the $_FILES array, which is empty in my service.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, works on local wamp PHP 5.3.4 !

```
public static function processRequest()
{
    case 'post':
       if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"] , "Images/" . $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"] )){
                    echo "move_uploaded_file SUCCESS ";
    ......................................                
}
......................................           
protected function executePost ($ch)
{
    $tmpfile = $_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'];
    $filename = basename($_FILES['image1']['name']);

    $data = array(
        'uploaded_file' => '@' . $tmpfile . ';filename='.$filename,
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);             
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
    //no need httpheaders
    $this->doExecute($ch); 
}
```

Thanks. Dave

Answer (score 0):

Check the encoding type of your POST. In a form it needs to be "multipart/form-data" so I'm assuming your POST REST call will need to have a similar encoding type for the file upload to work properly.